# Reverse a Python string without omitting start and end slice

Tags: python, reverse, slice

How do you reverse a Python string without omitting the start and end slice arguments?

```
word = "hello"
reversed_word = word[::-1]
```

I understand that this works, but how would I get the result by specifying the start and end indexes?

```
word = "hello"
reversed_word = word[?:?:-1]
```

It's hard to explain to students why `word[::-1]` reverses a string. It's better if I can give them logical reasoning rather than "it's the pythonic way".

The way I explain `word[::1]` is as follows: "You have not specified the start so it just starts from the start. You have not specified the end so it just goes until the end. Now the step is 1 so it just goes from the start to the end 1 character by 1." Now when my students see `word[::-1]` they are going to think "We have not specified the start or the end so it will go through the string -1 characters at a time?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Python 2 source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Objects/sliceobject.c), this is defined with ternary expressions:

> ```
> defstart = *step < 0 ? length-1 : 0;
> defstop = *step < 0 ? -1 : length;
> ```

So, when start and stop are not given,

**If step is negative:**

- start is length - 1
- stop is -1, (this is the C index, tricky to implement in Python, must be -length-1)

**If step is positive:**

- start is 0
- stop is length

So to answer this question:

> **How would I get the result by specifying the start and end indexes?**

To specify this yourself, use e.g. the following (put into a function for reusability)

```
def my_slice(word, step):
    '''slice word with only step'''
    start = len(word)-1 if step < 0 else 0
    stop = -len(word)-1 if step < 0 else len(word)
    return word[start:stop:step]


word = "hello"
step = -1
my_slice(word, step)
```

returns

```
'olleh'
```

Comment: Can't explain it better than showing the source. Very helpful thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Some other ways to reverse a string:

```
word = "hello"
reversed_word1 = word[-1: :-1] 
reversed_word2 = word[len(word)-1: :-1]   
reversed_word3 = word[:-len(word)-1 :-1]
```

One thing you should note about the slicing notation `a[i:j:k]` is that *omitting `i` and `j` doesn't always mean that `i` will become `0` and `j` will become `len(s)`. [It depends upon the sign of `k`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)*. By default `k` is `+1`.

- If `k` is +ve then the default value of `i` is `0` (start from the beginning). If it is -ve then the default value of `i` is `-1` (start from the end).
- If `k` is +ve then the default value of `j` is `len(s)` (stop at the end). If it is -ve then the default value of `j` is `-(len(s)+1)` (stop at the beginning).

Now you can explain your students how `Hello[::-1]` prints `olleH`.

Comment: this would make even more sense if `-(len(s)+1)` could just be 0. Because that is also the beginning

Comment: @Ogen; No. It is actually one past the `0`. `-len(s)` is equivalent to `0`.

Answer (score 13):

Not quite sure why, but the following will return the reverse of `word`:

```
word = "hello"
word[len(word):-(len(word)+1):-1]
```

Or...

```
word = "hello"
word[len(word):-len(word)-1:-1]
```

**Edit (Explanation):**

From jedward's comment:

> The middle parameter is the trickiest, but it's pretty straightforward
>   once you realize (a) negative indices to slice start/stop indicate
>   that you want to count "backwards" from the end of the string, and (b)
>   the stop index is exclusive, so it will "count" up to but stop
>   at/before the stop index. word[len(word):-len(word)-1:-1] is probably
>   more clear.

In response to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312383/reverse-python-string-without-omitting-start-and-end-slice/29312436?noredirect=1#comment46818437_29312436) comment:

The third value is actually the increment so you are telling Python that you want to start at the last letter then return all the (-1)st values up to the last one.

Here is an drawing (pulled together in a minute):

[image]

The drawing shows that we can also use this instead:

```
word = "hello"
word[-1:-len(word)-1:-1] #-1 as the first
```

Comment: That is weird... I have no idea why that works. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: The middle parameter is the trickiest, but it's pretty straightforward once you realize (a) negative indices to slice start/stop indicate that you want to count "backwards" from the end of the string, and (b) the stop index is *exclusive*, so it will "count" up to but stop at/before the stop index.  `word[len(word):-len(word)-1:-1]` might be a bit clearer.

Comment: @jedwards Can I quote you in my answer?

Comment: Don't even worry about quoting, just throw it in there :)

Comment: I thought that the 3rd parameter, step, is responsible for the direction. A negative step would mean go backwards from the end, a positive step would mean go forwards from the start. That makes intuitive sense to me.

Comment: @Ogen, you are correct that the step is responsible for the direction.  But you also need to specify the stop parameter with a negative index as well.  I'll try to illustrate why in a tiny comment box:  You might try `word[len(word):0:-1]` which would get you close, but you'd lose the first letter (since stop is exclusive), so then you might try to do `word[len(word):-1:-1]` which makes sense, but negative indices for start/stop are interpreted differently (that is, from the end of the string) -- so using -1 as a stop actually means the last character -- which will result in an empty string...

Comment: @Ogen (cont'd) so to "compensate" for the fact that python interprets negative start/stop indices as counting from the end of the string, you can't use `-1`, insead you have to use `-len(word)` -- but again, you'll be missing the first character of the original string / last of the reversed string.  So to fix this additional twist, you have to subtract *an additional* 1.

Comment: @jedwards Okay I understand now. I still think that only the step should be responsible for direction. The start and end parameters should just be used for the indices. I think this would be more clear and easier to understand but I guess it would affect other features of Python that I'm not aware of so that's okay.

Comment: @Ogen, there's a good blog post somewhere by Guido van Rossum about how he decided on the slicing notation -- let me dig it up.  EDIT: Here: [Why Python uses 0-based indexing](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html)

Comment: @jedwards This maybe?: https://plus.google.com/115212051037621986145/posts/YTUxbXYZyfi

Comment: @jakekimds yep, it looks like that google+ post inspired his blog post the following day, but they're a bit different, so possibly both worth reviewing -- nice find.

Comment: That post makes perfect sense. But it's only when you include the step parameter that the confusion arises because then the start, end and step parameters are all able to dictate the order of reading the string so it seems to conflict in my mind. That post doesn't show examples of string slicing with a non-default step parameter. But I understand that a sacrifice had to be made to keep the beautiful half-open intervals.

Comment: @jedwards Can you explain why the stdin is empty when the last one is omitted (`word[len(word):-len(word)-1]`)?

Comment: I know that the step needs to be -1 but I just can't explain why. The point of this question was to find a logical way to explain it to students that are in an introductory computer science course but it's proving harder than I thought.

Comment: I meant string not stdin in my last comment

Comment: @jakekimds sure, give me a few minutes and I'll throw together some code for an example.

Comment: @jakekimds [Here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/jheiv/1d0efd0a0bc39e73bffd) that shows one way you could implement the actual slicing, given an iterable (in this case, a string) and a slice object.  The last two slices are the ones that might interest you.  The second to last slice is the answer you gave (`[len(text):-len(text)-1:-1]`), the last answer has the same start and stop, but no step.  When step isn't provided, it defaults to 1 and the loop tries to count forward, but it's already *past* the end of the string starting at `len(text)`, so it stops immediately.

Comment: @jakekimds That looks really nice and it makes sense. Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 4):

If you do not specify a number for slice notation, Python will use `None` as a default.  So, you can just explicitly write the `None` values:

```
>>> word = "hello"
>>> word[None:None:-1]
'olleh'
>>>
```

Comment: I am trying to understand why the answer wouldnt be `word[len(word):-1:-1]`. To me this reads: "start from the end of the word, and go backwards until you reach -1 and stop". But this doesn't work.

Comment: Python doesn't knows that len(word) means "start from the end". Python thinks it is "Start from index that equals to some number". You need to read function definion in manual before using. There first number defined as "start" index.

Comment: @ogen negative start or end mean to count from the end of the string, not to stop when it goes below 0.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. I meant `word[len(word) - 1:-1:-1]`. So now the start index is the last index and the end index is -1 because it's exclusive so the last index will be 0.

Comment: `word[len(word)-1:-1:-1]` doesn't mean: "start from the end of the word, and go backwards until you reach -1 and stop". It means that: "Start from `-1` and stop when you reach at `-1`". As for string indices in python,  `-1` is equivalent to `len[string]-1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [27]: word
Out[27]: 'hello'

In [28]: word[-1:-6:-1]
Out[28]: 'olleh'
```

Why this works:

```
In [46]: word
Out[46]: 'hello' 

In [47]: word[-1] # you want o to be your first value
Out[47]: 'o'

In [48]: word[-5] # you want h to be your last value
Out[48]: 'h'

In [49]: word[-1:-6:-1] # therefore ending point should be one
Out[49]: 'olleh'        # past your last value that is -6
```

Answer (score 2):

The notation `string[begin:end:increment]` can be described with the following Python program:

```
def myreverse( string, begin, end, increment ):
  newstring = ""
  if begin >= 0 and end < 0:
    begin = -1
  for i in xrange(begin, end, increment):
    try:
      newstring += string[i]
    except IndexError:
      pass

  return newstring
```

Answer (score 1):

**Recursive approach:**

```
def reverse(word):
    if len(word) <= 1:
        return word

    return reverse(word[1:]) + word[0]
```

Comment: That works nicely but I'm not looking for a recursive solution. There should be values that I can put into the slice that makes logical sense.