# Issue reversing a list in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def fib2(n): #return Fibonacci series up to n
     """Return a list containing the Fibonacci series up to n."""
     result = []
     a, b = 0, 1
     while b < n:
          result.append(b) #see below
          a, b = b, a+b
     return result

#===========================================
f35 = fib2(35)     #call it
print (f35)        #write the result
```

Okay so that's what I have so far. That gives the output [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]. Which is fine, but I need it reversed. Showing [34, 21, 13, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]. I just can't figure out how to apply the reversed command or use the [::-1] method.

I keep getting a bunch of errors if I try to apply any of the above methods. I'm pretty new at this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Doesn't `[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34][::-1]` give you `[34, 21, 13, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
print (f35[::-1]) // Reversed list will be printed
```

There are [some other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29313612/2455888) around to reverse the list. All of them will work.

You can also use `reverse` method of list object

```
f35.reverse()
print(f35)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you so much. I kept messing up the parentheses or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of this

```
return result[::-1] # or list(reversed(result))
```

OR

```
f35 = fib2(35)
f35.reverse()
print(f35)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use `insert` instead of `append` to just build the list in the right order in the first place?

So instead of:

```
result.append(b)
```

Do:

```
result.insert(0, b)
```

That puts `b` at index 0 in the list and shoves all the other elements up one.